# Checkbox value in Display Mode = view & edit PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-selected-items

Happy Thursday!

I added  2 Checkbox controls inside the TypeOfPerson field data card. Trying to figure out to display the value of the checkbox on both Display Mode = View  | Display Mode = Edit

TypeOfPErson is a Column Type =  Choice in SharePoint

Hope i explain myself clearly

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image: Form]

[image: Edit Form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can only choose one of two options, then you'll either want a dropdown or a radio.

Radio is probably better in this instance as you have only two choices. If the number of choices grows then go to a dropdown.

For the display screen why not just use a label to display the name of the option selected.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two separate forms (`Form1` and `Form2`) which is unnecessary here. You might try adding a HomeScreen then with two options "New Item" and "Search Items":

**New record workflow:**

- From HomeScreen, user clicks "New Item" button
- `OnSelect` of the "New Item" button:

  - `NewForm(Form1)`
  - `Navigate(FormScreen, Fade)`
- User fills in all required fields and hits "Submit" button
- User taken to SuccessScreen then back to HomeScreen

**Search record workflow:**

- From HomeScreen, user clicks "Search Items" button
- `OnSelect` of the "Edit Item" button:

  - `Navigate(SearchScreen, Fade)`
- `OnVisible` of SearchScreen

  - `ClearCollect(colItems, Filter(dataSource, status=smart))`
- Gallery control on this screen with `Items` property set to `colItems`
- User clicks a "Right Arrow" icon within the Gallery to select a specific record from your data source to edit
- `OnSelect` of the "Right Arrow"

  - `EditForm(Form1)` //notice, its the SAME FORM
  - `Navigate(FormScreen, Fade)`
- Set the `Item` property of `Form1` to:

  - `If(Form1.Mode <> FormMode.New, gallery.Selected)`

You then set the `Default` values of Form1 controls to something like:
- `If(Form1.Mode = FormMode.New, Blank(), Parent.Default`

This is all from memory, so might need some minor tweaks, but the logic is there.

Comment: Thank you @SeaDude. Will give it a try and circle back